# How to call a rails method from in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, callback

I have this JQuery code:

```
$("p.exclamation, div#notification_box").live("mouseover", function() {

    });
```

and I want to call this rails method from inside the jQuery code as a callback:

```
def render_read
  self.user_notifications.where(:read => false).each do |n|
    n.read = true
    n.save
  end
end
```

This method is in my user model. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Make an AJAX call, set up a route, respond with a controller action and call your method.

```
# whatever.js
$("p.exclamation, div#notification_box").on("mouseover", function() {
  $.ajax("/users/render_read")
});

# routes.rb
resources :users do
  get :render_read, on: :collection 
  # or you may prefer to call this route on: :member
end

# users_controller.rb
def render_read
  @current_user.render_read
  # I made this part up, do whatever necessary to find the needed user here
end
```

*PS: This code is for Rails 3.x and Ruby 1.9.x*

Comment: There you go, simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 4):

It's good that you have that model code. We'll need to add a new action and make sure your route is setup. If you're using resources you'll have to add collection or member. Since you're doing an update I would choose `PUT` as the http method.

Here's an example route:

```
resources :user_notifications do
  collection do
    put 'render_read'
  end
end
```

Go ahead and add the `render_read` action to your controller.

Your jQuery code will look something like this:

```
$("p.exclamation, div#notification_box").live("mouseover", function() {   
  $.ajax({
    url: "/user_notifications/render_read",
    type: 'PUT'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set up a controller on the server side to call your `render_read` method and then you could use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) in your jQuery to make the request.

Answer (score 1):

Normally JavaScript works in the client side, but it's is also possible that your application draws a javaScript function for a each client. In that case you can use the `<%=` and tags `%>` in a .erb file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    new AClass.function({
        text: <%= Date.today %>
    });
});
</script>
```