# Ajax call to method defined in controller throwing back [object Object]

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, callback

I'm following this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5933309/1393002) and so am trying to call this method I defined:

```
class IngredientsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def get_restaurant_id(menu_id)
    Menu.find_by_id(menu_id).restaurant_id.to_i
  end
```

through an AJAX call:

```
m_id = $('#dish_menu_id').val()
$.ajax "/ingredients/get_restaurant_id(" + m_id + ")"
```

I've defined my **routes.rb** as such:

```
resources :ingredients do
  get :get_restaurant_id, on: :collection
end
```

But my `console.log($.ajax "/ingredients/get_restaurant_id(" + m_id + ")")` displays this error message:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/ingredients/get_restaurant_id(1) 404 (Not Found)
```

**I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Is there another way to pass the `m_id` parameter through an AJAX call?**

**Ideally, I'd like to have the AJAX call return the integer value of the restaurant ID.**

PS -- This is the alternative solution I've come up to my [original SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906452/how-to-make-a-simple-sql-query-in-jquery-to-find-one-id-from-another) about a problem I was trying to overcome.

---

### Edit 1

I now understand a little better as to what I'm doing with the GET/POST (I hope) so I redefined my method as such:

**ingredients_controller.rb**

```
def get_restaurant_id
  Menu.find_by_id(params[:m_id]).restaurant_id
end
```

But I get a `Template is missing` and `500 Internal Server Error`.

I get that there is no template for this. So is there any way I can have it just do a simply SQL query to get the restaurant ID and return it back to the Ajax call?

So my Ajax call looks like this now:

```
$.ajax "/ingredients/get_restaurant_id?m_id=" + m_id
```

---

### Edit 2: Almost There

I changed my method to this:

```
def get_restaurant_id
  menu_id = params[:m_id]    
  r_id = Menu.find_by_id(params[:m_id]).restaurant_id.to_s
  render :json => r_id 
end
```

And now in my Ajax I get an `Object` that has the answer within the `responseText` field but I can't seem to access it.

I've tried this:

```
r_id = $.ajax "/ingredients/get_restaurant_id?m_id=" + m_id
alert "After call to get_restaurant_id " + r_id.responseText
```

But get it as `undefined`.

The `Object` in my console log looks like this:

```
...
readyState: 4
responseText: "1"
setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
...
```

Comment: did you mean to do something like this? `"/ingredients?get_restaurant_id="+ m_id` or `"/ingredients/get_restaurant_id?m_id=" + m_id `

Comment: +1 for identiying Faraz lack of understanding of the GET/POST :P

Comment: Hmm. I'm kind of understanding what I'm doing wrong. I've updated my original post w/ my revision, error message, and ultimately what I'm trying to do w/ all this.

Comment: I've made another edit and its almost there. Just need a little help accessing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. Here's what I did:

**restaurants_controller.rb**

```
def get_restaurant_id 
  r_id = Menu.find_by_id(params[:m_id]).restaurant_id.to_s
  render :json => r_id 
end
```

Since I'm moving my method into the `restaurants_controller` from the `ingredients_controller`, make sure you also update your `routes.rb` to reflect this change. So it'll look like this:

```
resources :restaurants do
  get :get_restaurant_id, on: :collection
end
```

My jQuery/Ajax now looks like this:

```
m_id = $('#dish_menu_id').val() # To get the menu_id from the dropdown menu
r_id = "" # restaurant_id variable

# Call my get_restaurant_id method
request = $.ajax
  type: 'GET'
  url: "/restaurants/get_restaurant_id?m_id=" + m_id
  async: false
  success: (text) ->
    r_id = text

  console.log(request) # Just for programming purpose to show what I'm getting from AJAX
```

Now your `r_id` will hold the integer value of the `restaurant_id`